# how to do this query in rails to get search two columns from one table and one column from another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, where-clause

I have the following association:

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :author

```
 def self.search(search)
     where('title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
 end
```

I need to search for the author name as in the following:

```
 where('title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ? OR author_name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%" )
```

end

This obviously won't work as I have the author_id in the Resource table and not the author name field.

I'm a NOOB so any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the joins method to join the authors table.  See example below:

```
def self.search(search)
 joins(:author).where('title ILIKE ? OR description ILIKE ? OR authors.name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
end
```